# Getting a runtime error for my python code

Tags: python-3.x, runtime-error

I was solving the UVa 10963 problem
Here is the link to the problem:
https://onlinejudge.org/index.php?option=com_onlinejudge&Itemid=8&page=show_problem&problem=1904

here is my code in python

```py
a=int(input())
for i in range(1,a+1):
    b=input()
    c=int(input())
    d,e=map(int,input().split())
    summ=d-e
    for j in range(c-1):
        f,g=map(int,input().split())
        if ((f-g) != summ):
            if(i==a):
                print("no")
            else:
                print("no")
                print()
            break
    else:
        if(i==a):
            print("yes")
        else:
            print("yes")
            print()
```

I get runtime error, and I have no idea why.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: can you provide the exact error trace because I can't duplicate the error

Comment: @MatthewBarlowe It's from UVa, it does not give you the exact error sadly.
I have linked the question which contains all input output details and that is as much as I have

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay nevermind, I solved it.
For anyone else who happens to have a similar problem and stumbles upon this post in future, here's the solution.

So it turns out that on UVa, you can run into problems if you try to do a simple
`inp=input()` to take in a blank line as input

Instead, use `inp=sys.stdin.read()`  (from the sys library)
And then carefully manipulate it according to the requirements of the problem